# Garbled text at end of file. Is this encryption related?

Tags: windows, encryption, ntfs, encoding, sublime-text-3

**Preface:** About a month or so, we upgraded our work systems from a Windows 7 desktop to a Windows 8.1 Dell laptop. Laptop's file system is NTFS with [DDPE file encryption](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/ddpe-enterprise-edition/pd) and desktop's file system is NTFS, but no encryption. I am having issues honing into this specific problem, so I am asking a new question. I asked this over on stackoverflow and someone mentioned that superuser would probably be a better place for this question.

**Problem:** We're getting garbled text issues at the end of file with any extension. Randomly happens to some files on computer restarts. Randomly means it sometimes happens, sometimes doesn't. Happens on projects started on desktop and projects started on laptop. For the .sublime-workspace files, it doesn't matter if the project has been opened during the computer's uptime or not. For files within a project, seems to only happen to the files that are opened within the project. So files that are loaded in memory?

**Example:** filezilla.xml

```xml
        </LastServer>
    </Settings>
</FileZillZY_ ?
```

**Example:** Richmond2015.sublime-workspace

```xml
    "side_bar_width": 514.0,
    "status_bar_visible": true,
    "template_settings":
    {?c??A
```

**Attempts to fix:**

- changing between unix and windows line endings
- "ensure_newline_at_eof_on_save": true
- saving with different file encodings, some were defaulting to Western, changed to UTF-8

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SU! Does this happen with other editors?

Comment: Thanks! I started writing this comment saying that I hadn't opened filezilla.xml prior to FileZilla giving me the malformed error, but I may have opened it to have it not check for updates on startup. As for your question, I have not tried other editors.

Comment: A day or so after my last comment, Adobe CC stopped syncing. Logs pointed to ~/AppData/Roaming/Adobe/CoreSync/ACSLEng.cfg. Opened that config for the first time and sure enough, garbled text at EOF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

**Yes, the problem is related to the encryption.** Why is it doing what it is doing? Well, I can't answer that. But what I can do is — avoid it.

**To avoid the problem, evade the encryption.** I moved all of the folders of files that I didn't want altered into a directory that the encryption policy deemed exempt and created symlinks in their place.